# make a timer for a period of time

Tags: c++, windows

I want to make a timer that waits 4 seconds for example and then do something,

I did this but not working:

```
void wait(long seconds)
{
    seconds = seconds * 1000;
    Sleep(seconds);

}
```

but it tells me that 'Sleep' is undefined!!

Comment: `Sleep` is a Windows function - are you in fact compiling for Windows ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: @PaulR I am using visual studio on windows 7

Comment: OK - I've fixed your tags for you - please remember to tag with both language and platform in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C++11; there's a much better *platform independent way*. Use

```
#include<chrono>

std::chrono::seconds s(seconds);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(s);
```

Prior to C++11 there is no platform independent way of doing this. Here's how to do it on two platforms:

**Windows Pre C++11:**

```
#include <windows.h> /*This was your issue: you were not including this file*/

void sleep(unsigned milliseconds)
{
    Sleep(milliseconds);
}
```

**Posix Pre C++11:**

```
#include <unistd.h>

void sleep(unsigned milliseconds)
{
    usleep(milliseconds * 1000/*convert to microseconds*/);
}
```